# which is faster, creating new variable vs reusing old variable?

Tags: java, performance, variables

which is faster creating new variable or reusing old one for java programming language?
example

case 1: creating

```
int x = 5;
int var = 1;
```

case 2: reusing old one

```
int x = 5;
x = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure one is faster than the other, though the bottom might use slightly less space on the stack.  In general, you should avoid declaring new variables unnecessarily, and this is a good practice in general.

Comment: I would definitely create a new variable if it will be used for something unrelated. Always give variables meaningful names, and keep that meaning in tact throughout your application. In terms of performance, they will be identical because they both make an assignment. (And if they were objects, they would both become available for garbage collection)

Comment: Strike that, they wouldn't be quite identical because the first would allocate new memory for the pointer/primitive in the stack (which takes nearly 0 time, but time indeed)

Comment: If your code's performance is impacted by variable allocation, you might be using the wrong language.

Comment: If you're asking the question, it's because you tried to benchmark the difference (I hope you did at least that before asking). And if you couldn't find a noticeable difference, then it probably means the answer to the question doesn't really matter.  Your time will be better spent making the code more readable and maintainable, rather than focusing on undetectable micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

"Which is faster?" is the wrong question. "Which is correct for the algorithm?" is the right question.

As a rule, you only reuse a variable if it needs to hold a new primitive value or point to a different object, because it is the variable that represents the current state. If the variable is reassigned to hold something that *means* something different, you should not do that but use a new variable.

So `sum += item;` is a valid reuse of the variable `sum`. But

```
foo = 42;
buyQuantity(foo);
 ...
foo = 23;
sendMessages(foo);
```

is not a valid reuse of `foo`.

A related but different question is whether you should reuse an object to hold new values. Not usually. For example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
for (int ix = 0; ix < MAX_ITERS; ++ix )
{
    foo.clear();
    foo.fill();
    process(foo);
}
```

is worse than:

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < MAX_ITERS; ++ix )
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.fill();
    process(foo);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why `foo.clear()` would be bad? You kinda glossed over that.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm not concern about the algorithm correction i just want to know which will execute faster? the new variable or reusing old one?

Comment: @4castle, the variable scoped outside the loop is only correct if it's used outside the loop. If it's used only inside the loop then it's scope should be inside the loop. It's a matter of scope correctness. Furthermore, hanging on to the referenced object too long risks promoting it to the tenured generation, which is usually less optimal than keeping it in the quicker-to-collect young generation.

Comment: As I said, Dalal Alghomlas, that is not actually the useful question, and as @sstan hinted, your benchmark is the only way to know. Faster to get wrong answers is not the right way to code, and neither is faster to cause more bugs. Out of curiosity, what _did_ your benchmarks show?

Answer (score 2):

I did an small and simple test: Running a loop on a large (10 million) array and fill each element with a number.

- Test1 : define a var before the loop and use that
- Test2 : define a const inside the loop

To make the test as honest as possible, all other operations were removed.

### Code

```js
//@ts-nocheck

const maxInt = 10000000

// fill Array with a number
let A = [...Array(maxInt)].map(x => 10);

// Test 1 : Variable declared before
let x
console.time('test1')
B = A.map((a) => {
    x = 3
    return x
})
console.timeEnd('test1')

// Test 2 : Const variable declared in the Loop, every time
console.time('test2')
C = A.map((a) => {
    const x = 3
    return x
})
console.timeEnd('test2')
```

### Test results

The test was run multiple times and on avarage (not calculated) the results were:

```sh
test1: 190.656ms
test2: 282.766ms
```

(Running on a Macbook with enough memory and normal CPU)

My careful conclusion: Creating a Const every time does have a slight performance impact.